# Delivering string value between 2 different methods

Tags: java

I'm starting with java and have a problem by returning the right value through my BMI calculator. I'd really appreciate your help!

Kind regards,
Andy...

```
public class bmirechner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ergebnis ="";
        bmirechner(ergebnis);
        System.out.println(ergebnis);
    }

    public static String bmirechner(String ant){

        int kg=0;
        float length=0;
        double bmi=0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie ihr Körpergewicht ein.");
        kg = sc.nextInt();      
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie ihre Größe ein.");
        length = sc.nextFloat();

        bmi = kg/(length*length);

        if(bmi>=18.5&&bmi<=24) {
            return ant="Normalgewicht";
        }
        else if(bmi>=24&&bmi<30) {
            return ant="Übergewicht";
        }
        else if(bmi>=30&&bmi<35) {
            return ant="Adipositas Grad 1";
        }
        else if(bmi>=35&&bmi<40) {
            return ant="Adipositas Grad 2";
        }
        else if(bmi>40) {
            return ant="Adipositas Grad 3";
        }
        else return ant="nicht vorhanden";

    }

}
```

Comment: in java string is immutable you can not change it, also I would suggest not trying to get result vi passing parameters, do your homework first https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: Drop the "ant=" from the return statements; you either assign or return a value.

Answer (score 1):

I not very familiar with java but im thinking about the `return ant="Normalgewicht";` part. I would write only `return "Normalgewicht";`

Answer (score 1):

in your if statements you have some cases where the code doesn't know what to do

```
    if(bmi>=18.5&&bmi<=24) {
        return ant="Normalgewicht";
    }
    else if(bmi>=24&&bmi<30) {
        return ant="Übergewicht";
    }
```

here if you input 24, it will only call the first method. you should change the first if condition to just < 24 rather than <=24.

```
    else if(bmi>=35&&bmi<40) {
        return ant="Adipositas Grad 2";
    }
    else if(bmi>40) {
        return ant="Adipositas Grad 3";
    }
```

here you have no way to handle what will happen if 40 is input, as bmi<40 and bmi>40 are exclusive of the value. you probably want to change the last if condition to if(bmi>40).

You also dont need  `return ant=" Normalgewicht";`, you would rather have `return "Normalgewicht";` and have `String ergebnis = bmirechner();` in your main method.